# 404 Not found - Apache CentOS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I am running CentOS 5.11 with apache/2.2.3(named) server.

I am able to view my site homepage, so I can confirm php is running correct.
However when trying to naviate to one if the pages like *domain.com/wp_post1001*(wordpress, mysql driven) I see the following message.

### Not Found

The requested URL */wp_post1001* was not found on this server.

*Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at domain.com Port 80*

I see the following rows in my log file

**nano /var/log/httpd/domain.com-error**

```
[Mon Dec 22 16:24:11 2014] [error]  File does not exist:  /home/FTP/domain.com/www/wp_post1001
[Mon Dec 22 16:24:14 2014] [error]  File does not exist:  /home/FTP/domain.com/www/wp_post12
[Mon Dec 22 16:25:24 2014] [error]  File does not exist:  /home/FTP/domain.com/www/wp_post402
[Mon Dec 22 16:25:34 2014] [error]  File does not exist:  /home/FTP/domain.com/www/wp_post22
```

I have made sure my .htaccess file exists.
I have added **RewriteEngine on** in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** at the highest level global block, and also within my domains  block.

Fixed this by changing AllowOverride None to All

```
    <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: You can mark your own response below as the answer, given that you found it (this is [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). However, if you'd searched you may have found [other relevant responses](http://serverfault.com/questions/497050/apache-allowoverride-options-directive)

Answer (score 3):

AllowOverride is set to *None* by default, Must be changed to *All*

```
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```